# Is it possible to call C++ functions from JavaScript using Emscripten?

Tags: c++, emscripten

I'm trying to generate a JavaScript wrapper from a C++ library (so that C++ code can be used on the client side in a web browser), but I'm not sure which tools would be best for this purpose. Using Emscripten, is it possible to generate a JavaScript library from a C++ library, so that C++ functions can be called in JavaScript?

Comment: As a proof-of-concept, would it be possible to generate a JavaScript library from math.h (a standard C++ library for mathematical functions)?

Comment: `math.h` is a header, it contains only declaration, no implementation. You want `libm` or the Windows equivalent, the library containing the implementations for these functions. However, this domain specifically (low-level math) is fraught with architecture-specific code, e.g. inline assembler or compiler-built-in functions to use CPU architecture-specific tricks. It's probably not best for a proof of concept.

Comment: @delnan What would be a better library to use for a proof-of-concept, then?

Comment: I have no specific proposals. To get up and running, I'd probably use simple hand-written snippets. To test against real-world code later, I'd probably look into some boost libraries that aren't header-only (or compile one of their examples). Alternatively, C libraries don't suffer from name mangling (when properly surrounded by `extern "C"`) which makes the interaction less painful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to call compiled C++ functions from JavaScript, according to [Emscripten's official documentation.](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html)